# Exclude User Commits in CruiseControl

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

How can I exclude commits in SVN by a specific user from triggering a build in Cruise Control .NET version 1.8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the documation:
http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Filtered

To troubleshoot any problems run `ccnet.exe` (in the `server` folder of the installation) from the command line and look at the exception. In my case I was naming one of the elements incorrectly.